# Comparing a linear model with a squared independent variable and a non-linear (Poisson) model

Tags: regression, interaction, nonlinear-regression, poisson-regression

I have a question about choosing between a linear and a non-linear model for estimating the effects of different treatments on the growth/presence of an insect on a plant. The outcome variable is a count of the number of insects, and there are three randomised treatments (treatment A, treatment B and treatment A and B combined - AB) and one control group. We track the count of insects over 9 weeks and there are seven units in each treatment group (9x7x4 = 252 total observations). I want to estimate the effects of the treatments on the growth of the insect population. Please note there are no "pre-treatment observations", but the insect populations and plants are identical across all units at the start.

From preliminary plots, there is clearly a squared/quadratic relationship between insect numbers and time. I had two thoughts on how to estimate the effects I am interested in given this non-linearity and the data at hand.

1. Use a pooled linear regression model with time, time^2 and an interaction between time and the treatments entering the model. This would allow me to estimate the "linear" effect of each treatment on the rate of growth of the insect population. However, the interaction effect between time and treatment may be hard to interpret with a squared term in the mix.
2. On the other hand, I could use a Poisson non-linear pooled regression model (which better aligns with "count" nature of the dependent variable). In this case, I would still run interactions between time and the treatment variables (but would not include a squared time term I believe).

When I try both methods, the linear approach gives much more significance and the results are more appealing. However, I'm not sure if the approach is valid.

Given the smallish sample size and descriptions above, are there justifications for the methods in 1) and 2) and would either be clearly preferred over the other?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Using a fixed polynomial in a regression model is dangerous unless there's a strong theoretical justification. It's usually safest to model continuous variables like time flexibly, for example with regression splines. See Chapter 7 of the second edition of [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www.statlearning.com/).

Although a Poisson model isn't strictly a linear regression model, it is a standard "[generalized linear model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/generalized-linear-model/info)." If you have count data, a Poisson model is a good place to start (although you might need to extend to a "quasi-Poisson" or negative binomial model in some circumstances). You can certainly use polynomials or regression splines as predictors with a Poisson model, as the "non-linearity" is in the link between the linear predictor and the mean outcome.

So you can have the best of both: handle your outcome appropriately with a count model and fit time flexibly, in a way that lets the data tell you about the functional form of the relationship with outcome.

You are correct that it becomes more difficult to put simple explanations on interactions when there are polynomials or splines involved. Post-modeling tests like Wald tests on combinations of coefficients can still evaluate the overall linearity with respect to time and the overall significance of the treatment-time interaction. Alternatively, Frank Harrell's [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) provides an operator (`%ia%`) that allows for fitting a continuous predictor flexibly while only including interactions of other predictors with the linear part of the fit.